# How to show tooltip using folium using JSON file?

Tags: python, json, leaflet, data-visualization, folium

I want to show the country name when I hover up on the map. I am using JSON file for countries coordinates. Here is my python code:

```
import folium
 

m = folium.Map(location=[47.516232 , 47.516232],
           zoom_start=5,
           tiles='https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
           attr='My Data Attribution')


geoJson = r'/Users/bader/Desktop/pandaTable/european-union-countries.json'

g = folium.GeoJson(

    geoJson,
    name='geoJson').add_to(m)

folium.GeoJsonToolTip(fields=["name"]).add_to(g)


m.save('map.html')
```

I am getting error for this line `folium.GeoJsonToolTip(fields=["name"]).add_to(g)`
I know its from the fields name but i don't know what is the correct field name :(

Here is some pics for JSON file. i need to know where is the names of the countries to show them on the map:[The beginning of json code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbEA8.png)

[Each several lines there is smilier code like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Q5vu.png)

[Here is the map pic of EU countries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AH9O0.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It's necessary get the geojson file (not the json)...

I get in https://data.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/european-union-countries@public/export/

And the adjusted code is:

```
import folium

m = folium.Map(
    location=[47.516232 , 47.516232],
    zoom_start=5,
    tiles='https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
    attr='My Data Attribution'
)

folium.GeoJson(
    #r'/Users/bader/Desktop/pandaTable/european-union-countries.json',
    '/home/michel/Downloads/european-union-countries.geojson',    
    name='geoJson',
    tooltip=folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(
        fields=['name_sort', 'gu_a3'],
        aliases=['Name', 'Code'],
        sticky=True,
        opacity=0.9,
        direction='right',
    ),
).add_to(m)

m.save('map.html')
```